# Objective C: UIScrollView (pagingEnabled): When Next Page Enters Start The Animation

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, cgpoint

I'm sorry for the title i don't know what to write there.

I have a scrollView with many pages and in each page there are different animations that should start when the user switch to that page.

i tried this:

```
if (CGPointEqualToPoint (CGPointZero, CGPointZero))
{
    //start animation
}
```

it worked only for the first page

when i changed it to `CGPointEqualToPoint (CGPointMake (768, 0), CGPointZero)` for the next page, it's not working.

i am trying to use this `

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset
```

but then i found out that it is not working when the scrollview `pagingEnabled` is `YES`.

Comment: You're going to have to explain the context more. Are you doing this within scrollViewDidScroll?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

by using this delegate method of scroll view you can get when your first page finish scrolling and by keeping conditions you can start animation.

Answer (score 0):

Use the scroll view's `contentOffset` to learn where you are.

Also, see this question to discover what delegate methods you need to be using: [How to detect when a UIScrollView has finished scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993280/how-to-detect-when-a-uiscrollview-has-finished-scrolling)