# Detect when a user swipes past a certain point in a UICollectionView's scrollViewWillBeginDragging?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview

In my collectionView the cells are the size of the entire screen, I use `vertical` scrolling, and I have `.isPagingEnabled = true`. I needed to prevent the user from swiping fast. Changing the `.decelerationRate` didn't work. The only thing that I found was to disable/enable the `scrollView` as the user swipes which almost works fine.

In the pic below, when the swiping starts, I disable the scrollView and show a red label at the top that says "cv Disabled". When swiping ends because the user lifted their finger, I enable the scrollView and remove the label. But when I swipe a hairline bit and quickly lift my finger from the cell, the red label never disappears and the scroll stays disabled. The orange arrow points to the next cell with a beige background that's about to be shown when I subtly swiped.

[image]

In the code below using both tries everything works fine when scrolling past a certain point occurs  like full screen or a quarter of the screen. The issue is if I subtly swipe a hairline bit, the `scrollView` stays disabled because the methods `myScrollView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` are in never gets fired.

1st try:

```
var myScrollView: UIScrollView?

func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if myScrollView == nil {
        myScrollView = scrollView
    }

    myScrollView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

    showRedDisabledLabel()
}

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    myScrollView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    removeRedDisabledLabel()
}
```

2nd try:

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if myScrollView == nil {
        myScrollView = scrollView
    }

    myScrollView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

    showRedDisabledLabel()
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: self)
    perform(#selector(UIScrollViewDelegate.scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation), with: nil, afterDelay: 0.3)
}

func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    myScrollView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    removeRedDisabledLabel()

    NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: self)
}
```

This problem literally only occurs when I swipe that hairline bit and quickly lift my finger, every other time the code from both tries works perfectly. The question is **in `scrollViewWillBeginDragging`, how can I detect when a user swipes past a certain point so that I can then set `myScrollView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false`**

Comment: *"prevent the user from swiping fast"* ... Do you mean swiping from cell to cell to cell? Or do you mean you want the view to move slower than the touch movement?

Comment: Hey, what’s up! Swiping from cell to cell.

Comment: @DonMag I found a workaround below, thanks for looking into it :)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to to determine how much a user swiped in `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` but I did find a workaround to the actual problem of hairline scrolling. I put `myScrollView?.isUserInteractionEnabled` and the redLabel into their own functions, combined this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8010066/4833705) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1857162/4833705), created an instance property named `isScrolling`, and use `didSet` to determine if it's scrolling or not and call the functions from there:

```
// Properties
var myScrollView: UIScrollView?

var isScrolling = false {
    didSet {

        if isScrolling {

            disableScrollView()

        } else {

            enableScrollView()
        }
    }
}

// My 2 Functions
func disableScrollView() {
    myScrollView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    showRedDisabledLabel()
}

func enableScrollView() {
    myScrollView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    removeRedDisabledLabel()
}

// UIScrollView Delegate Methods
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    
    if myScrollView == nil {
        myScrollView = scrollView
    }
    
    isScrolling = true
}

func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    
    if !decelerate {
        isScrolling = false
    }
}

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    
    isScrolling = false
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: self)
    perform(#selector(UIScrollViewDelegate.scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation), with: nil, afterDelay: 0.3)
}

func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    isScrolling = false
    NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: self)
}
```